# Modifiying colours with color balance

Tags: javascript, colors, photoshop-script

In JavaScript I can adjust the image's color balance with a function like

```
colorBalanceLayer(-50,0,0)

function colourBalanceLayer(cya, mag, yel)
{
  // cyan, magenta, yellow values are between -100 & +100
    var id713 = charIDToTypeID( "ClrB" );
    var desc162 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var id714 = charIDToTypeID( "ShdL" );
    var list37 = new ActionList();
    list37.putInteger( 0 );
    list37.putInteger( 0 );
    list37.putInteger( 0 );
    desc162.putList( id714, list37 );
    var id715 = charIDToTypeID( "MdtL" );
    var list38 = new ActionList();
    list38.putInteger( cya );
    list38.putInteger( mag );
    list38.putInteger( yel );
    desc162.putList( id715, list38 );
    var id716 = charIDToTypeID( "HghL" );
    var list39 = new ActionList();
    list39.putInteger( 0 );
    list39.putInteger( 0 );
    list39.putInteger( 0 );
    desc162.putList( id716, list39 );
    var id717 = charIDToTypeID( "PrsL" );
    desc162.putBoolean( id717, true );
    executeAction( id713, desc162, DialogModes.NO );
}
```

This works fine, and in my example adds a shedload of cyan to the midtones of the image. What I want to know is this: if I wanted to modify an RGB color by a similar value of -50 cyan (like in the example above) how would I go about it? Would it be best to change the color to CMKY, adjust appropriately, and then change back to RGB. Only I read somewhere that I was best to go from RGB to L*ab first (which I know how to do).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use that function on RGB colors you have to convert them into CMY since `colorBalanceLayer` is designed to work with CMY colors. It can easily be done with following function:

```
// r, g, b and c, m, y are in the range of 0 to 255

function rgb_cmy(r, g, b) {
    return [].map.call(arguments, function(v) {return 255 - v;});
}

// return value is an array of the form: [cyan, magenta, yellow]
```

After processing convert back to RGB using the same function:

```
rgb_cmy(c, m, y) // returns an array of the form: [red, green, blue]
```

Should we convert to L*ab as an in-between step ? **No.**

RGB and CMY are two different colorspaces with the same size: That means: both contains the same number of colors. But both spaces doesn't cover each other exactly. That means: RGB contains some colors that cannot exactly be expressed as an CMY color, and also contrariwise. So each conversion can introduce some inaccuracy.

The L*ab colorspace is much larger than the others and covers both RGB and CMY completely. That means: each RGB (or CMY) color can exactly be expressed as an L*ab color, but there are many L*ab colors not beeing expressible with RGB or CMY.

Having a RGB color that's not exactly fit in CMY following happens:

```
RGB --inaccurate--> CMY --inaccurate--> RGB // output !== input
RGB --accurate--> L*ab --inaccurate--> CMY --accurate--> L*ab --inaccurate--> RGB
```

We see that same inaccuracies are introduced.

**EDIT** Inside `colorBalanceLayer` you call some other functions. I can't see what exactly they do, so I can give the following only as a draft.

Of course it is possible to change cyan, magenta, or yellow inside a RGB color without any conversion. To do so we have two things to know:

1) CMY works with printed pigments, RGB with emitted light, so they are complementary by brightness. That means: adding some value to CMY makes the color darker, adding some value to RGB makes it brighter.

2) The colorwheels of RGB and CMY are turned by 60 degree, so they are complementary by colors. That means: the opposite colors of both build the complementary pairs cyan/red, magenta/green, and yellow/blue.

So following operations causes identic results (CMY left-, RGB right-hand):

```
cyan += 20   ===   red -= 20;
magenta  -= 30   ===   green += 30;
yellow += 40   ===   blue -= 40;
```

It might be possible to adjust your functions so they would work with RGB as well.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Now all I need to do is correlate the values of a color balance change. RGB 128, 128, 128 +100 red goes to 156, 97, 97 & 60,60,60 goes to 91,33,33. It looks like the red shifts up by 30 and the others move down by the same. I'll have to investigate further to get more accurate values.

Comment: @GhoulFool Changing color balance has to keep the brightness of the color stable. So if `red += 50` there should be `green -= 25` and `blue -= 25`.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question: it's possible to return the value of the "balanced" color. It's not an elegant solution:

```
colourBalanceLayer("C0FFEE", 100,0,0);

function colourBalanceLayer(hexcol, cya, mag, yel)
{

  var pixH = 10;
  var pixV = 10;

  // create a document to work with
  var docRef = app.documents.add(pixH *2, pixV *2, 72, "colours")
  var newDoc = app.activeDocument;

  // =======================================================
  var id70 = charIDToTypeID( "Fl  " );
  var desc18 = new ActionDescriptor();
  var id71 = charIDToTypeID( "From" );
  var desc19 = new ActionDescriptor();
  var id72 = charIDToTypeID( "Hrzn" );
  var id73 = charIDToTypeID( "#Pxl" );
  desc19.putUnitDouble( id72, id73, 10.000000 );
  var id74 = charIDToTypeID( "Vrtc" );
  var id75 = charIDToTypeID( "#Pxl" );
  desc19.putUnitDouble( id74, id75, 9.000000 );
  var id76 = charIDToTypeID( "Pnt " );
  desc18.putObject( id71, id76, desc19 );
  var id77 = charIDToTypeID( "Tlrn" );
  desc18.putInteger( id77, 32 );
  var id78 = charIDToTypeID( "AntA" );
  desc18.putBoolean( id78, true );
  var id79 = charIDToTypeID( "Usng" );
  var id80 = charIDToTypeID( "FlCn" );
  var id81 = charIDToTypeID( "FrgC" );
  desc18.putEnumerated( id79, id80, id81 );
  executeAction( id70, desc18, DialogModes.NO );

  // cyan, magenta, yellow values are between -100 & +100
  var id713 = charIDToTypeID( "ClrB" );
  var desc162 = new ActionDescriptor();
  var id714 = charIDToTypeID( "ShdL" );
  var list37 = new ActionList();
  list37.putInteger( 0 );
  list37.putInteger( 0 );
  list37.putInteger( 0 );
  desc162.putList( id714, list37 );
  var id715 = charIDToTypeID( "MdtL" );
  var list38 = new ActionList();
  list38.putInteger( cya );
  list38.putInteger( mag );
  list38.putInteger( yel );
  desc162.putList( id715, list38 );
  var id716 = charIDToTypeID( "HghL" );
  var list39 = new ActionList();
  list39.putInteger( 0 );
  list39.putInteger( 0 );
  list39.putInteger( 0 );
  desc162.putList( id716, list39 );
  var id717 = charIDToTypeID( "PrsL" );
  desc162.putBoolean( id717, true );
  executeAction( id713, desc162, DialogModes.NO );

  // =======================================================
  var id40 = charIDToTypeID( "setd" );
  var desc11 = new ActionDescriptor();
  var id41 = charIDToTypeID( "null" );
  var ref5 = new ActionReference();
  var id42 = charIDToTypeID( "Clr " );
  var id43 = charIDToTypeID( "FrgC" );
  ref5.putProperty( id42, id43 );
  desc11.putReference( id41, ref5 );
  var id44 = charIDToTypeID( "T   " );
  var desc12 = new ActionDescriptor();
  var id45 = charIDToTypeID( "Rd  " );
  desc12.putDouble( id45, 255.000000 );
  var id46 = charIDToTypeID( "Grn " );
  desc12.putDouble( id46, 255.000000 );
  var id47 = charIDToTypeID( "Bl  " );
  desc12.putDouble( id47, 255.000000 );
  var id48 = charIDToTypeID( "RGBC" );
  desc11.putObject( id44, id48, desc12 );
  executeAction( id40, desc11, DialogModes.NO );

  var selRegion = null;
  selRegion = Array(Array(pixH, pixV),
  Array(pixH + 1, pixV),
  Array(pixH + 1, pixV + 1),
  Array(pixH, pixV + 1),
  Array(pixH, pixV));
  newDoc.selection.select(selRegion);
  var histR = newDoc.channels.getByName("Red").histogram;
  var histG = newDoc.channels.getByName("Green").histogram;
  var histB = newDoc.channels.getByName("Blue").histogram;
  var returnColor = new RGBColor();

  for (iHistR in histR)
  {
  if (histR[iHistR]!=0)
    {
      returnColor.red = iHistR;
    }
  }
  for (iHistG in histG)
  {
  if(histG[iHistG]!=0)
    {
      returnColor.green = iHistG;
    }
  }
  for (iHistB in histB)
  {
    if(histB[iHistB]!=0)
    {
      returnColor.blue = iHistB;
    }
  }

  alert(returnColor.red+","+returnColor.green+","+returnColor.blue);

  return returnColor;
}
```